# Gibbs sampler fails to converge

Tags: python, random, sampling, normal-distribution, mcmc

I've been trying to understand Gibbs sampling for some time. Recently, I saw a video that made a good deal of sense.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_08GKWHFWo

The author used Gibbs sampling to converge on the mean values (theta_1 and theta_2) of a bivariate normal distribution, using the process as follows:

init: Initialize theta_2 to a random value.

Loop:

1. sample theta_1 conditioned on theta_2 as N~(p(theta_2), [1-p**2])
2. sample theta_2 conditioned on theta_1 as N~(p(theta_1), [1-p**2])

(repeat until convergence.)

I tried this on my own and ran into an issue:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

rv = multivariate_normal(mean=[0.5, -0.2], cov=[[1, 0.9], [0.9, 1]])

rv.mean
>>> 
array([ 0.5, -0.2])

rv.cov
>>>
array([[1. , 0.9],
       [0.9, 1. ]])

import numpy as np
samples = []

curr_t2 = np.random.rand()
def gibbs(iterations=5000):
    theta_1 = np.random.normal(curr_t2, (1-0.9**2), None)
    theta_2 = np.random.normal(theta_1, (1-0.9**2), None)
    samples.append((theta_1,theta_2))
    for i in range(iterations-1):
        theta_1 = np.random.normal(theta_2, (1-0.9**2), None)
        theta_2 = np.random.normal(theta_1, (1-0.9**2), None)
        samples.append((theta_1,theta_2))
gibbs()

sum([a for a,b in samples])/len(samples)
>>>
4.745736136676516

sum([b for a,b in samples])/len(samples)
>>>
4.746816908769834
```

Now, I see where I messed up. I found theta_1 conditioned on theta_2's actual value, not its probability. Likewise, I found theta_2 conditioned on theta_1's actual value, not its probability.

Where I'm stuck is, how do I evaluate the probability of either theta taking on any given observed value?

Two options I see: probability density (based on location on normal curve) AND p-value (integration from infinity (and/or negative infinity) to the observed value). Neither of these solutions sound "right."

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps my video wasn't clear enough. The algorithm does not converge "on the mean values" but rather it converges to samples from the distribution. Nonetheless, averages of samples from the distributions will converge to their respective mean values.

The issue is with your conditional means. In the video, I choose marginal means that were zero to reduce notation. If you have non-zero marginal means, the [conditional expectation for a bivariate normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2) involves the marginal means, the correlation, and the standard deviations (which are 1 in your bivariate normal). The updated code is

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

mu1 = 0.5
mu2 = -0.2
rv = multivariate_normal(mean=[mu1, mu2], cov=[[1, 0.9], [0.9, 1]])

samples = []

curr_t2 = np.random.rand()
def gibbs(iterations=5000):
    theta_1 = np.random.normal(mu1 + 0.9 * (curr_t2-mu2), (1-0.9**2), None)
    theta_2 = np.random.normal(mu2 + 0.9 * (theta_1-mu1), (1-0.9**2), None)
    samples.append((theta_1,theta_2))
    for i in range(iterations-1):
        theta_1 = np.random.normal(mu1 + 0.9 * (theta_2-mu2), (1-0.9**2), None)
        theta_2 = np.random.normal(mu2 + 0.9 * (theta_1-mu1), (1-0.9**2), None)
        samples.append((theta_1,theta_2))

gibbs()

sum([a for a,b in samples])/len(samples)
sum([b for a,b in samples])/len(samples)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful!